# Is binning data valid prior to Pearson correlation?

Tags: correlation, binning

Is it acceptable to bin data, calculate the mean of the bins, and then derive the Pearson correlation coefficient on the basis of these means? It seems a somewhat fishy procedure to me in that (if you think of the data as a population sample) the scatter of these means will be the standard error of the mean and hence very tight if $n$ is large.  So you will probably get a much better correlation coefficient than from the primary data, and that seems wrong.
On the other hand, people often average replicate measurements before a correlation calculation which isn't very different.

Comment: What would be the purpose of binning in this particular case?

Comment: There is no evident point to binning before correlation unless you are directly interested in looking at the relationship between binned variables.

Comment: Binning data that is continuous and then computing a correlation is like cutting off your leg and then getting crutches.

Comment: My guess is that the binning was done to make the correlation look better than it was in reality.  The primary data gave a poor correlation but, when binned and averaged, it looked much better. I think that because each bin mean value will have a tiny standard error (there were 100s of points in each bin), the meaned values give an apparently beautiful correlation.

Comment: Are you reviewing a paper or something?

Comment: No - it is a published paper (in chemistry) I've recently read that uses this approach and I was wondering whether it is valid.

Comment: Why stop there? By using just two bins you can always get a correlation coefficient of $100$% :-). In contrast, averaging replicate measurements *is* different because it invokes a different model of data behavior and leads to a different inference (about the expectations of the replicates rather than the replicates themselves).

Comment: I'd be interested to know more (or pointed to a reference) regarding the differences between binning and replicates.  While intuitively there is a difference, I can't define it precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the same as your question, but on a related note, I remember reading an article a while back (either The American Statistician or Chance magazine, sometime between 2000 and 2003) that showed that for any dataset of 2 variables where they are pretty much uncorrelated you can find a way to bin the "predictor" variable, then take the average of the response variable within each bin and depending on how you do the binning show either a positive relationship or a negative relationship in a table or simple plot.

Comment: The excellent article you allude to is @Article{wai06fin,
  author =    {Wainer, Howard},
  title =    {Finding what is not there through the unfortunate
binning of results: {The} {Mendel} effect},
  journal =   {Chance},
  year =    2006,
  volume =   19,
  number =   1,
  pages =   {49-56},
  annote =   {can find bins that yield either positive or negative
association;especially pertinent when effects are small;``With four
parameters, I can fit an elephant; with five, I can make it wiggle its
trunk.'' - John von Neumann}
}

Comment: @FrankHarrell, thanks for the reference, I remembered a couple of years off.

Comment: @GregSnow maybe you could edit for the reference? https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09332480.2006.10722771

Answer (score 0):

Correlation coefficient is a measure of uncertainty in predicting value Y from value X measured for an individual sampled object, such as a patient. In focusing on this prediction you do not 'bin' individual readouts: your blood sample is your blood sample not other's. If however the nature of your data permits binning / averaging it normally means that you do not care about individual readouts (happy to mix them together)  but want to see if there is a TREND in your sample. Here, you look for a (linear) regression and its significance instead because the correlation coeffcient would depend  directly on the way you bin your data. Somehow, most biological papers ignore this.

Answer (score -2):

The main reason to bin data is to allow for the possibility of a nonlinear relationship between the variables. The Pearson correlation measures strength of *linear* association, so it doesn't work well when the relationship is nonlinear.

There are obviously much better ways to handle this issue than binning. For example, you might fit a nonlinear or local regression model and correlate the predicted and actual response values (although this assumes that a predictor-response approach is valid, whereas correlation is symmetric). Binning is just a way of solving the problem of nonlinearity that people without a statistics background or statistical tools might use.

Comment: Binning has absolutely nothing with helping to find a nonlinear relationship.